# JavaScript Geocoding does not start search

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, geocoding

Well I am currently moving some functions for google maps into a seperate file. In my other file I create some main function search(), in which I create this workflow with the other file included.
The problem I get is the geocoder.geocode() function, which worked fine until today, and I can't figure out what went wrong. The geocoder gets created and then steps over the function geocoder.geocode() without actually doing something. Does anyone have an idea?

This is a bit of my main file.js:

```
//set the point.
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.379, -3.444);
//initialize the google map.
initializeMap(latlng, null, null, null);
//get selected country text from dropdown.
var address = $('#country option:selected').text();
//get entered postcode from textbox.
if ($("#postcode").val() != "") {
    address = $('#postcode').val() + ", " + address;
}
//do a google search and store the result.
var result = googleSearch(address);
```

The address would be something like: "NX5 897, United States".
And this is the googleSearch in the functionCollection.js

```
 function googleSearch(address) {

    var result;

    //setting up a geocoder search.
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            result = results[0];
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            result = null;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning result of async request geocoder.geocode().
Send a callback to googleSearch or just call your function from within the function like.

```
   geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    result = results[0];
}
else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    result = null;
}
somefunction(result); or callback(result)
```

});

Comment: to test you can replace somefunction with alert(result) at the given place.

Comment: The problem is that the geocoder.geocode() does not even reach the function I created there and in which you advise me to add this callback. It creates a geocoder, but it kinda skips the whole thing, and if I have a look at the result in the end, it is still undefined.

Comment: You are not getting the point, you send request to google servers using geocoder.geocode() asychronously, that means as soon as you call geocoder.geocode() you move immediately to return results step, which ofcourse is not evaluated yet because you havent received response from google yet. Google sends you reply in the callback function(results,status). Place alert where I have suggested once and see.

Comment: I've tested your advise, and the var result still is undefined, even if I go to another function with it, as you told me.

Comment: This answer is correct, you need to understand the nature of asynchronous functions.

Comment: Okay, I found a way to do it now. Thanks for this solution. Just wanted to be sure before I tick it :)

Comment: you should post what you did to fix it. I am having the same issue right now and i'd love to know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: address },
```

you are passing the variable `address` twice.

change the variable name to something else, like `myaddress` and try

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: myaddress },
```

Comment: I thought that might be it aswell, but I can change the variable name address to anything and it still doesn't work. Also I tried the version where it is:
`geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }`
And it didn't work.